# Winforms using Entity Framework with edmx; retrieve connexion string from registry

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, edmx

I am working on a Winforms application using Entity Framework 6 with an `.EDMX` diagram which generates the context and entities for me.

The connection string is stored in `app.config` by default.

I want to change the source of my connection string, and I want to retrieve it from the Windows registry.

How can I do that?

Comment: I would ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just encrypt the connection string in the web.config?

Comment: i whant to protect access to the connexion string (simple users dont need to see it), and in the same time keep easy access for system Administors to modify the connexion string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities();
ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "...";
```

You can read connection string data from registry and assgin it to "ConnectionString" property.

It works but you have to assgin connection string everytime a new context object is created and also do not remove the original connection string from the app.config file.